# Rails - Associations with API

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I'm working on an API in Rails and have hit a wall. I'm missing something stupid I imagine, but I can't see it.

https://gist.github.com/3989396

I can not get associations passed in the item.json to create an association. I thought that Rails would hook these up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relations for the accounts need to be fixed like so:

item.rb:

```
belongs_to :expense_account, class_name: "Account"
belongs_to :income_account, class_name: "Account"
```

account.rb:

```
has_many :items, inverse_of: :expense_account
has_many :items, inverse_of: :income_account
```